# Android Change text to dots and apply animation

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am developing android app and I want to add some feature of this app https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.altervista.luma23.BannerLEDLite like it my application also get text and change it to dots and also with dot background and than moving this text in a direction. 
I search about it but I can't find any help about it that how to change text to dots with dot background and than move text in a direction.

Thanks in advance and sorry for my weak english.

Comment: i want just guide me about it, like what library i can use for it or what will be my starting point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple solution will be to use Images: one image for the background (simply an image with black dots) and one image as an overlay for the text.

Then, you can just use regular text and put the overlay image above it (use a png which has transparent holes at the same size of the dots in the background image).

Comment: +1 Nice trick. If you know the text won't change you can even use 2 images. But image + texrview can do the trick

Comment: Thanks you give me such a nice idea for it, now i am implement it i hope i will help me.

Answer (score 0):

You have seen that Glow Pad which Android OS used to unlock your phone. Such sample is created by rock3r called **[GlowPadBackPort](https://github.com/rock3r/GlowPadBackport)**.

You need to modify code as it works on touch and you want it static. But this will help you.